# Twitch TV API accessing property name value and updating it

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have created a list of Twitch TV thumbnails using JSON. I would like to create an option where I can click on thumbnail and popup tab with that video to appear. For that, I need to access to API code "options" property and change "channel" value.
I have tried to access that property and change value in function popup() which is triggered by clicking on thumbnail ;

```
<div id="popup">
<div id="videoWrapper">

<script src= "http://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 315,
        channel: "monstercat", 
        //video: "v123456789"   
    };
    var player = new Twitch.Player("test", options);
    player.setVolume(0.01);
    //player.setMuted(true);



        //Popup Tab with streaming video
            function popup(){
                $('#popup').show();
                options.channel = 'nl_kripp';   
            }


</script>
```

Do You maybe know what I am doing wrong here becasue this is not working?

Comment: You will need to change the channel field then call the api again.

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely right. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered correctly by tmutton. Let me explain what I did for all others.
I needed to call Api again after I changed the property "options" "channel" value to 'nl_kripp' in function popup.

```
            //Popup Tab with streaming video
            function popup(){
                $('#popup').show();
                var player = 'none';
                options.channel = 'nl_kripp';

                var player = new Twitch.Player("test", options);
            }
```